# Github workflows usage limits

Tags: github, github-actions

So I read that there are some restrictions on Github workflows. However couldn't really understand this point.

Workflow run time - Each workflow run is limited to 35 days. If a workflow run reaches this limit, the workflow run is cancelled. This period includes execution duration, and time spent on waiting and approval.

What does it mean? Also how long do you think this workflow would last for?
https://github.com/ayushjain01/Self-Updating-Readme

Comment: 35 days refers to the duration of one workflow run, but your readme updates are going to take a few seconds each time only. The 35 days limit isn't relevant for that.

Comment: @BenjaminW.so my worflow would run for eternity?

Comment: I just read this too. I am considering to self-host gitlab or github. It seems gitlab does not have limits on self-hosted version. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/instance_limits.html Could some experienced github users explain more on github self-hosted limits?

Answer (score 0):

The **Workflow run time** is the time your workflow will take to finish, including the wait time before the jobs are really started. By what I saw in your executions, they are taking only seconds to finish, so you will never reach this limit.